# How to store pictures within an app and call them to screen?

Tags: android

I want to create an app that has pictures Ive taken or created and allows users to browse through them.  Ive got how to use buttons but I just cant figure out how to store the pictures within the apk file that gets uploaded to market. Im really new to android development and Ive been through some tutorials and have a couple books but for right now Im stuck and would greatly appreciate a push in the right direction. I know it should be easy to do but I just cant find anything describing what Im trying to do.

Comment: do you mean you wish to download the pictures in the app and display them? Or do you really want to hard code and compile the pictures into the application? Seems like that would defeat the purpose. Having a web resource from which the app downloads the pictures seems more useful. If however, you are just storing in the app, then diretrospect's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be for you to store your pictures in the res/drawable folder of your Android project. You can then access these images with myImageView.setResource(R.drawable.name_of_image_without_the_filetype);

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/index.html